# How to convert local animation keyframes of humanoid bone to global ones?

Tags: animation, bones

I have an animated humanoid model and I want to make a weapon move together with its right hand, a.k.a. have the same animation keyframes as the hand. The problem is that the hand has its keyframes relative to its parent bone and I couldn't figure how to convert them to global values. Assigning the weapon as child object is not an option because I'm making this for a video game animation framework which requires the weapon to have its own animations.

Comment: The typical way to do this is to, yes, use a child-of, and to *bake* that constraint to keyframes.  Default .fbx export should bake automatically last I checked.  If not, you can use "bake action" operation with visual keying and clear constraints.